# Send automatic email when placing customer in a customergroup

Tags: magento-1.6, email-templates

I've been searching for a way to send an automatic email when placing a customer in a certain customergroup. I have had no luck finding exactly how to get that done if it's even possible. Suggestions with programming or through an extension would be welcome

Answer (score 3):

It ought to be possible to hook into the `customer_save_after` or `adminhtml_customer_save_after` event, then compare `getData('customer_group_id')` vs `getOrigData('customer_group_id')` to see whether it was changed. If then the customer group Id fits the ID of the customer group you want to send the email for, you can use the Zend mail

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom("fromemail","fromname");
$mail->addTo("toemail","toname");
$mail->setSubject("subject");
$mail->setBodyHtml(" body text")
$mail->send();
```

to send the email.

Didn't test this yet, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                <yourmodelobserver>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>yourmodel/observer</class>
                    <method>mysendmail</method>
                </yourmodelobserver>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

php code

```
    mysendmail($object){

     if ($object->getData('group_id') != $object->getOrigData('group_id')) {
//send mail
    } }
```